# Is there any Dremio or Drill connection string for C# or .NET program user

Tags: apache-drill, dremio

I am using dremio to query a large amount of data and it is working very fine. It has rest API to fetch data but the only constraint is that it can give 500 records as a result. In java, Dremio community has given jdbc connection string but our project is in .net or c# so we need the connection string to fetch the massive amount of data from dremio. If the connection string is not there for C# then can anyone suggest us how do we use JDBC connection string in C#.

Answer (score 1):

Drill and Dremio have ODBC interface for that purpose, see:
https://drill.apache.org/docs/configuring-odbc/
https://docs.dremio.com/drivers/dremio-odbc-driver.html

So you can setup up your C# project to use ODBC connection string instead of JDBC:
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/connect-to-an-odbc-source-49b0cf4d-ef78-4ad1-b224-39091c067953

or [programmatically](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.odbc.odbcconnection?view=netframework-4.8):

```
static private void InsertRow(string connectionString)
{
    string queryString = 
        "INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerID, CompanyName) Values('NWIND', 'Northwind Traders')";
    OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand(queryString);

    using (OdbcConnection connection = new OdbcConnection(connectionString))
    {
        command.Connection = connection;
        connection.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        // The connection is automatically closed at 
        // the end of the Using block.
    }
}
```

where connection string [examples](https://drill.apache.org/docs/odbc-configuration-reference/#connection-string-examples):

> DRIVER=MapR Drill ODBC
>   Driver;AdvancedProperties={HandshakeTimeout=0;QueryTimeout=0;TimestampTZDisplayTimezone=utc;ExcludedSchemas=sys,INFORMATION_SCHEMA;};Catalog=DRILL;Schema=hivestg;ConnectionType=Direct;Host=192.168.202.147;Port=31010
>
> DRIVER=MapR Drill ODBC
>   Driver;AdvancedProperties={HandshakeTimeout=0;QueryTimeout=0;TimestampTZDisplayTimezone=utc;ExcludedSchemas=sys,
>   INFORMATION_SCHEMA;};Catalog=DRILL;Schema=;ConnectionType=ZooKeeper;ZKQuorum=192.168.39.43:5181;ZKClusterID=drillbits1